# Индекс в не границ

Tags: сравнение, java

Может кто то помочь? Получаю ошибку `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1` когда запускаю данный код. Сама ошибка в функции удаления. Как исправить? StringBuffer и StringTokenizer обязательны. И еще, как можно упростить код?

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class main {
  public static int i, n;
  public static boolean orly = false;
  public static StringBuffer input, tokenStr;
  public static StringTokenizer out;
  public static char aChar;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    input = new StringBuffer("some text");
    System.out.println("Начальная строка - " + input.toString());
    input = new StringBuffer(input.toString().replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z А-Я а-я]", ""));
    if (input.toString().trim().length() != 0) {
      out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
      System.out.println("Форматированная строка - " + input.toString());
      n = (out.countTokens());
      String[] charSet = { "a", "e", "o", "u", "y" };
      for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
        tokenStr = new StringBuffer(out.nextToken());
        aChar = (tokenStr.charAt(0));
        String firstchar = tokenStr.toString().substring(0,1);
        if (tokenStr.length() > 1) {
          for (int j = 0; j <= charSet.length-1; j++) {
                if ((!firstchar.equals(charSet[j])) || (!firstchar.toUpperCase().equals(charSet[j]))) {
              input.delete(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())+ tokenStr.length() + 1);
            }
         }
           } else {
                        input.deleteCharAt(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Расскажите, на какой строке вылетает, и чего именно вы хотите добиться этой строкой.

Comment: Кстати, результатом функции `indexOf` вполне может быть -1, так что я бы не использовал полученное таким образом значение как аргумент функции delete без проверки.

Comment: Вот в том то и проблема, не знаю как выполнить эту проверку

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы поленились разбить код на функции.

Comment: Вы не знаете, как проверить значение типа `int`, равно ли оно `-1`? Я бы посоветовал книжку по программированию. Любую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде есть 2 потенциально опасных места:

1. `String firstchar = tokenStr.toString().substring(0,1);` выкинет исключение если строка пустая
2. `input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())` легко может вернуть -1, тогда не избежать проблем.

P.S. Замечания по штилю кодирования:

1. Принято писать: `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`, а не `for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)` - читается легче, да и код будет чутка оптимальнее
2. `tokenStr.toString()` я бы оформил в виде переменной
3. В данном контексте `StringBuilder` более уместен, нежели `StringBuffer` - подумайте почему?
4. `StringTokenizer out;` я бы не стал именовать переменную, `out`, конечно не **keyword**, но все же мешает восприятию на фоне `System.out`
5. Разбейте код на мелкие функции - алгоритм станет яснее.